# Eval() is not working in LWC Javascript, although it is working fine in LWC playground

Tags: javascript, salesforce, eval, lwc

I tried running this code in the LWC playground and it runs fine for me

When I try to run the same code inside a method in LWC component in salesforce (JavaScript), it's throwing an error.

```js
import {
  LightningElement
} from 'lwc';

export default class InputText extends LightningElement {

  handleCommit(event) {
    var value = event.target.value
    console.log("Value: " + value);

    let validationRule = 'A.length > 5';
    console.log("Validation Rule: " + validationRule);

    let n = validationRule.replace('A', 'value');
    console.log("N: " + n);

    let x = eval(n);
    console.log("X: " + x);

  }
}
```

```html
<lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" oncommit={handleCommit}></lightning-input>
```

ERROR:

[image: LWC Javascript Error]

Comment: Please [edit] and add the error (after searching for the error first, perhaps it has already been answered)

Comment: Please check the image for reference.

Comment: And the console logs show "Value: textFromInput"? What does `console.log("N: " + n);` show in the two environments?

Comment: console.log("N: " +n); shows value.length > 5 for both the environment

Comment: console.log("Value: " +value); shows the value entered in the field.

Comment: Wrap the eval in try catch and show the e.message

Comment: Error:ReferenceError: value is not defined